Cannot run an ARIMA model obtained via auto.arima in R
I did an extensive search for time series data using auto.arima() function in R. Since it is taking a long time to find the optimal model, I want to save the model obtained from auto.arima() and plug it into Arima() function. However, I get a "non-stationary AR part from CSS" error when I put the same model into Arima() function.
Here is auto.arima() code:
autoarima.Fit <- auto.arima(ts.data, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE,
                          seasonal = FALSE, max.p = 10, max.q = 10, max.order = 20)

The optimal model is Arima(8,0,2) with non-zero mean. Then, I write the following code; however, I get an error.
# ARIMA parameters (ARIMA(p, d, q)(P, D, Q)[period])
ARIMA.Param      <- c(8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7)
Include.Mean     <- TRUE
Include.Constant <- FALSE
Include.Drift    <- FALSE

# Fit Arima Model
Arima.Fit <- Arima(ts.data,
                     order = ARIMA.Param[1:3],
                     seasonal = list(order = ARIMA.Param[4:6], period = ARIMA.Param[7]),
                     include.mean = Include.Mean,
                     include.constant = Include.Constant,
                     include.drift = Include.Drift)

Here is the ts.data:
dput(ts.data)
structure(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), tsp = c(1, 1202, 1), class = "ts")

What am I doing wrong?

auto.arima() returns the optimal model. You don't need to estimate it again using Arima().
But if you did want to estimate it again, use method = "ML" since that is what auto.arima() uses in the last step.
And you have contradictory arguments. include.constant and include.mean are doing the same thing here. (See the help file for Arima().) The value for include.constant is over-riding the value of include.mean. Use one or the other, not both.

Thanks, Dr. Hyndman! As I said in the question, auto.arima function takes a couple of minutes to fit the model and I need to fit many models. Therefore, I want to get the optimal model with auto.arima and feed it to the Arima function that takes very short to fit the model. I am also just setting one of include.constant and include.mean to TRUE. They are in the code but mostly set to FALSE.

My point is that feeding the model to Arima() is pointless. You already have the model. Save it and use it. If you want to apply the same model to a different time series, you can pass it via the model argument.

Dr. @Rob Hyndman. Similar to this problem, when I fit the model using auto.arima function in R, ARIMA(2,1,1) model is selected with AIC=6618.16. However, when I played around with the model, I found that ARIMA(6,1,8) gives an AIC=6528.37. Which one should I choose? Is using a model with higher parameters safe?

Compare them using tscv and see what works best.
